# How to add a data to mysql table via Hibernate(one-to-Many)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 mysql tables: Accounts and Mails.
Accounts consist of id and user data.
Mails consist of id, user_id, data and foreign key user_id -> Accounts.key (fk_Users)

How I can add and get data to Mails table for current user_id via hibernate?
I tried some examples from google, but they create excess tables or foreign keys and I don't like it.

Comment: @nachokk I tried this example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/OneToManyMappedBy.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Account class:

```
public class Account {
private Integer id;
private Something userData;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="account", cascade=CascadeType.ALL);
private Set<Mail> mails;

}
```

Mail class:

```
public class Mail {

private Integer id;
private Othersomething data;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id" , referencedColumnName="your foreign key here in Account table")
@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Account account;

}
```

And then when you are retrieving in your DAO class

```
Query query =sess.createQuery("FROM Account");//hql or criteria here or native sql
List result = query.list();
```

Comment: Your example is not working. IDE said: that mappedBy parameter is wrong. I removed them. Than it said, that insertable and updatable parameter should be false. I changed it. And now program merging two databases into one. It's not working.

Comment: now it's working. Thanks! 
Do you know, why hibernate loading the old entity class or old table, which was deleted? :)

Comment: did u commit your changes in db? do u still having mapped? btw mark as solved

Comment: I started server only. No actions, no commits. And yes, i'm having mapped

Comment: see your hibernate.cfg if you have old entity class mapped, and check this hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create if is it in create then will create  in db the table